# Процедуры в SQL

Tags: sql

Как процедурой увеличить сумму на 15%?

Comment: Какой именно sql-сервер? MySQL? PgSQL? MsSQL? Oracle?

Comment: сумму чего?

Answer (score 6):

Умножить на 1.15

Answer (score 5):

Если вы имеете в виду поле таблицы:

1) Изменить **только** при выборке:

```
  SELECT ( `field_name` * 1.15 ) as `field_name` FROM `table`
```

2) Изменить хранящиеся записи:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field_name` = `field_name` * 1.15;
```